# jquery checkbox prepend - works separately, but not when put together inside function

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I`m new to javascript and jquery, but very eager to learn.

My end goal is to make a popup, in which a table of contents is displayed, with links, as is normal in a table of contents. This table of contents is called "Print adjust". just before every chapter headline inside the table of contents, I want a checkbox. If ticked, this checkbox will remove that chapter from the document. In addition, I want one checkbox that if ticked, ticks all the other checkboxes, and removes all chapters in the document. If all chapter specific checkboxes are checked, the master checkbox will be automatically checked.
I have tested parts of the code separately, but have challenges when I put it into the "Print adjust" function. The table of contents is fully operational, checkboxes are diplayed in fromt of every headline inside the TOC, but when I expect the checkboc class "justone" to be inserted, the "class "Master" is inserted on every line - the master should only be one checkbox inside a separate div, and that should be the checkbox "to rule them all".
This checkbox is not inserted at all, but all the other checkboxes get this class. In the div I want this checkbox, only text input fields are displayed - many of them.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Here is the part of the function I`m struggling with:

```
var check= document.createElement ('input');
check.type= "checkbox";
check.id= "CHECK" + sectionNumber;
check.className="justone";

$("input[type='checkbox'].justone").change(function(){
    var a = $("input[type='checkbox'].justone");
    if(a.length == a.filter(":checked").length){
        $('.containerhideall').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.containerhideall').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.justone').change(function(){
    if($('.justone:checked').length==0){
        $('#purpose_scope').show();
    }else{
        $('#purpose_scope').hide();
        $('.justone:checked').each(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('data-ptag')).show();
        }) 
    }});

    var MASTERcheck= document.createElement ('input');
    MASTERcheck.type= "checkbox";
    MASTERcheck.id= "MASTER";
    MASTERcheck.className="containerhideall";
    MASTERcheck.innerHTML=sectionNumber;

    $('.containerhideall').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$('.containerhideall').change(function(){
    if($('.containerhideall:checked').length==0){
        $('.screensteps-section').show();
    }else{
        $('.screensteps-section').hide();
        $('.containerhideall:checked').each(function(){
            $('#'+$(this).attr('data-ptag')).show();
        })
    }
});

$('.checkall').prepend (MASTERcheck);
    $('.PRINTEntry').each(function(n) {
    (this).prepend (check);
});
```

Comment: Additional comment: The code above does only hide elements with specific ID, I want the id`s for these chapters in the document to be created dynamically, and the checkboxes to dynamically be "connected" to these chapters. Meaning, that if I open a new document, the checkboxes will automatically be functional on the chapters they are displayed in front of in the TOC.

Comment: One thing looking at your code, you are creating a `MASTERcheck` element but look your assigning the `attributes` to `check` element which you have already created in begining

Comment: Second thing,  you are creating check boxes with `var check` and `var MASTERcheck` but where your assign/appending to the html..?

Comment: **Your code looks incomplete.**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for Your reply. The var’s (check and MASTERcheck) Are prepended in the bottom of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, and special thanks to SwapNeil for his input. I`m embarrassed that I didn`t see it myself. After correcting the var MASTER check attributes, most of the issues were solved - checkboxes appeared as expected, and the functionality was as expected. The only thing is that it seems like an event is bubbeling up, making the same amount of checkboxes, as there are chapters in the document. expect"stopPropagation may be the solution, but never used this before. if somebody have any inputs on that, it is very welcome. By the way, I will update the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Mutating variables can be tricky. Id suggest avoiding that where possible. Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to say exactly how you'd be best going about this. But I think this will point you in the right direction:

```
@media print {
  .hideFromPrint {
    display: none;
  }
}

<div class="TOC">
  <div class="chapter">
    <span>chapter 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter">
    <span>chapter 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter">
    <span>chapter 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <input class="checkbox all hide-chapter" type="checkbox"><span>hide all chapters</span>
  </div>
</div>

$('<input class="checkbox single hide-chapter" type="checkbox">')
  .prependTo('.chapter')
  .on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.chapter')
      .removeClass('hideFromPrint')
      .addClass(this.checked ? 'hideFromPrint' : '');
    $('.checkbox.all')
      .prop('checked', $('.checkbox.single').length === $('.checkbox.single:checked').length)
  });

$('.checkbox.all').on('click', function() {
    $('.checkbox.single').prop('checked', this.checked)
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v1y92Lak/64/

#### Some things to note:

The single checkboxes are binded after they are dynamically added. jQuery doesn't work like css, that is, where css is applied to anything with the right class regardless of when it's added, jQuery can only work with what's currently in the DOM. It doesn't matter if you use a class that already has an event listener bound to it if the element didn't exist when you added the bind. I know this caught me up alot at first.

Rather than removing the chapters you don't want, I'm using a nifty css property that hides it from being printed. Theory being less DOM manipulation is better.

I'm using click rather than change to prevent issues with the checkboxes changing each other.